# Can't remove my folder from SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to remove my folder from SVN completely. As some people mentioned here, I right-clicked on my folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Delete. Then, from a parent folder I did Commit. This deleted it from my file system, but it's still there in the SVN repo. I usually don't have any problems removing folders, so I'm not sure what's going on...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to commit the file itself instead of the parent file after deletion?

Comment: What do you mean? When I did "right-clicked on my folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Delete," that folder was instantly deleted locally. So that's why I had to commit the parent folder.

Comment: Oh, seems like it would just put a delete flag on it until you posted the commit...I may be mistaken on that.  Either way, the parent commit should work.

Comment: Actually, now I can't even add anything to the repo. I don't know what's going on. My folder has a green checkmark icon, so it should have added it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've done the process correctly.

right-click -> TortoiseSVN -> Delete.   Then commit the change.  If this hasn't removed the file from your repository:

1.)I would try updating to an earlier version, then repeating. 
2.)Reboot your system and repeat above.
3.)Remove all files, and then re-add them.

If none of this works, try updating to the latest version of SVN, if you haven't already, and repeating above. This happened to me recently, wish I could tell you exactly what I did (other than all this tinkering) to get it to work again.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your folder, select Repo-Browser and delete the folder directly from your repository.